# Creating An Alexa Bot Using The Microsoft Bot Framework in SDK V4

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

Could you help us on how to create Alexa Bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework in SDK V4?
Tried referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/integrations/alexa which is in SDK V3. But we need to implement using Microsoft Bot Framework in SDK V4 using NodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

Bot Framework doesn't have an official channel for Alexa at this time. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for all of the currently-supported channels and their respective documentation.

You may want to try the [`alexa-bridge`](https://github.com/CatalystCode/alexa-bridge), although it's a bit dated and not officially supported.

There's also an unofficial [.NET Alexa adapter for BotBuilder](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Alexa) that works with v4. You may find [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2018/04/27/azure-and-alexa-creating-conversation-with-ease/) useful in implementing it, as well. Unfortunately, there isn't a similar adapter written in NodeJS.